# How to get 'allJava' from sourceSets with Kotlin Gradle DSL in Gradle 4.10.3?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, maven-publish

I'm trying to follow the Maven Publish guide from Gradle 4.10.2 documentation, but having some difficulties as it's all in Groovy. Here is what the example says to do:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.allJava
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar) {
    from javadoc
    classifier = 'javadoc'
}
```

and here is what I'm trying to do:

```
tasks.register<Jar>("sourcesJar") {
    from(project(":core").sourceSets.allJava)
    classifier = "sources"
}

tasks.register<Jar>("javadocJar") {
    from(tasks["javadoc"])
    classifier = "javadoc"
}
```

`allJava` is returning not found, unfortunately. What is the correct way to do this in the Kotlin Gradle DSL For Gradle Version 4.10.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct `build.gradle.kts` syntax for *Kotlin DSL* **1.1.3** should be:

```kotlin
plugins {
    `java-library`
    `maven-publish`
}

tasks.register<Jar>("sourcesJar") {
    from(sourceSets.main.get().allJava)
    archiveClassifier.set("sources")
}

tasks.register<Jar>("javadocJar") {
    from(tasks.javadoc)
    archiveClassifier.set("javadoc")
}
```

Btw, `classifier` property is marked as `@Deprecated` - you should use `archiveClassifier` instead.

---

**[UPDATE]**

However, *Gradle* **4.10.3** has *Kotlin DSL* **1.0-rc-6**, therefore `build.gradle.kts` should be like:

```kotlin
plugins {
    `java-library`
    `maven-publish`
}

tasks.register<Jar>("sourcesJar") {
    from(sourceSets["main"].allJava)
    classifier = "sources"
}

tasks.register<Jar>("javadocJar") {
    from(tasks["javadoc"])
    classifier = "javadoc"
}
```